# Worklight-based Dojo app not supporting click events

Tags: ios, xcode, dojo, ibm-mobilefirst

We have a mobile app developed using worklight and dojo which works on android.
We are trying to port the same on ios.

Development is done on a Mac.

We installed worklight 6.2 and tried to deploy the app on ios simulator using xcode 6 and xcode 5 which have ios 8 and ios 7 sdks . But the app is not working (click events are not triggered from dojo components)

It seems that dojo is supported only till ios6.

ios 6 is supported in xcode 4.x but the app generated using worklight 6.2 doesn't compile on xcode 4.

Also looks like on mac OS 10.9.4 (mavericks) i cant have any other version of worklight which can support xcode 4 .

So currently i am blocked and not able to progress . Since we have already developed using dojo it will take a long time if we have to get rid of dojo .

Answer (score 0):

1. Worklight does not support Xcode 4 since Worklight 6.0.0.x; you must use Xcode 5 or 6.
2. For Dojo support in iOS8 you need to upgrade your Worklight installation to a version that adds Dojo support for iOS8. See the following tech note for instructions: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21684538